# I want to give a Bar a certain Width depending on the ticks of the x-Axis

Tags: html, css, reactjs, charts

I am working with ChartJs and React and now i have a mixed chart containing three line charts and one Bar Chart. See below the imageLink. The chart is working perfect, but I want to create some bars which have a different Width. How can i set the Width of the first Bar from Tick 0 to Tick 49? I searched alot and have not found anything that helped.
[My imagination of displaying the first Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJUYw.png)

```
  //The Dataset of the Bar-Chart
 {
    label: "Blocks",
    yAxisID: 'second-y-axis',
    data: [[0,23]],
    type: 'bar',
    barPercentage: 0.5,
    barThickness: 60,
    minBarLength: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
  }



//My Line Component
    <Line
        data={chartData.data}
        height={800}
        width={1400}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "bottom"
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                max: 506,
                min: 0,
                stepSize: 1,
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              id: 'first-y-axis',
              position: "right",
              gridLines: { color: "#131c2b", zeroLineColor: '#03fc24' }

            }, {
              id: 'second-y-axis',
              position: "left",
              gridLines: { zeroLineColor: '#03fc24' }
            }, {
              id: 'third-y-axis',
              position: "left",
            }]

          },
            
        
        }
        }
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by using another line instead of a Bar. So i can set the x, and Y and then the line is stepped. With the fill property it looks like an Bar so it works.